# Script to create multiple AD groups and set email (exchange is not used)

Tags: powershell

Powershell novice here. I need a script to create bulk AD groups and set the email address for the group. We do not use exchange. I have not been able to find good examples when not using exchange.

```
$Example = get-content c:\temp\Example.txt

foreach($Example in $Example){

New-ADGroup -Name "$Example.###" -SamAccountName "$Example.###" -Email "$Example.###@Anywhere.com" -ParentContainer "OU=THERE,OU=Organization,DC=HERE,DC=NET" -GroupType "Security" -GroupScope "Global"

}
```

Comment: Have a closer look at the variable names you are using.. The loop uses the same variable (`$Example`) as iteration var AND as collection var. Then in the `New-ADGroup` line you suddenly use an undefined variable `$Exampler` and even double the `$` at one point. Also, make sure the SamAccountName doesn't get to long.. Active Directory Users and Computers imposes the 20 character limit on sAMAccountName for backwards compatability, although the Schema allows the length of up to 256 characters.

Comment: Also, Import-CSV is superior to get-content in that the contents will build a collection  made of instances of a custom powershell object.  I would use more specific variable names  I.e. `$Groups = import-csv c:\temp\groups.txt; foreach($Group in $Groups)...`

Comment: @Theo "Exampler" was a total typo. I was trying to quickly modiy my script so as not to show my actual data. I have edited my example.

Comment: You are however still the same variable ($Example) as both iteration var AND as collection var. What is in the `c:\temp\Example.txt` ? a set of group names each on its own line or.. What happens if you run this. Problems? Error messages? Please add these to the question aswell zo we know what you are actually asking.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for your reply. What I am asking is how to set the email attribute for a group. I am trying to create multiple groups and set the email address. Note that we do not use exchange. The results of my research keeps pointing me at resolutions for exchange. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`New-AdGroup` doesn't have a parameter `Email`. You will have to use

```
-OtherAttributes @{mail = "$Example.###@Anywhere.com"}
```

PS. If the dot after the variable leads to problems, you can also format like

```
-OtherAttributes @{mail = ('{0}.###@Anywhere.com' -f $Example)}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.